# How to tab complete screen -r in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, autocomplete, zsh, gnu-screen

I want to tab complete the command `screen -r` in Ubuntu so that I can recover previous screens more easily. I know the `screen -x` command, however I still need `screen -r` in the situation where more than one screens exist.

I find that this tab completion feature does not exist in every Ubuntu machine. Sometimes, in the same machine, the tab completion works for bash shell but fails for zsh shell.

Can anyone tell me how to configure this tab completion feature for bash and zsh in Ubuntu?

===============================Some Facts================================

Here are some useful facts I found after asking this question. I think these facts can serve as workarounds to some extent.

I find that, even if I don't have tab completion support, I can also use part of the screen name to recover my screen. For example, given a screen `12354.pts-0.slave9`, I can recover it by simply typing `screen -r 1` if no other screen name starts with 1.

As for zsh, if it can not tab complete `screen -r 1`, it can possibly tab complete `screen -r 0`. Here `0` comes from the substring `pts-0`, which means you can use other parts of the name for tab completion.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/a/372593/145134

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy I think OP wants sth different: not screen-sessions behaving like bash, but rather when running screen -r from within a current bash session they want tab completion to show existing screen sessions (similar like ls tab would show files in the current directory)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, under
`/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/`
there are bash tab completions scripts for different executables. The one for screen is 
`/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/screen`.
Further, in my .bashrc, tab completion is activated this way:

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

I.e., you should also have the file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`.

I think copying

1. The relevant part from the `.bashrc` file
2. The file `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`
3. The screen completion file `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/screen`

should do the job for you. You should be able to copy them from a system where screen -r tab completion works as desired.

**Note**: `.bashrc` is only read for login shells. If you have a non-login shell, you need to include the tab completion related things into `.profile` or other scripts which are read for non-login shells.

Answer (score 0):

For me the screen bash completion file did not exist.
So I did this:

1. `sudo vim /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/screen` and pasted the screen content taken from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GArik/bash-completion/master/completions/screen.
2. `exec bash` to load it.

#### Screen file content:

```
# bash completion for screen                               -*- shell-script -*-

_screen_sessions()
{
    local sessions=( $( command screen -ls | sed -ne \
        's|^\t\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\.[^\t]\{1,\}\).*'"$1"'.*$|\1|p' ) )
    if [[ $cur == +([0-9])?(.*) ]]; then
        # Complete sessions including pid prefixes
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '${sessions[@]}' -- "$cur" ) )
    else
        # Create unique completions, dropping pids where possible
        local -A res
        local i tmp
        for i in ${sessions[@]}; do
            res[${i/#+([0-9])./}]+=" $i"
        done
        for i in ${!res[@]}; do
            [[ ${res[$i]} == \ *\ * ]] && tmp+=" ${res[$i]}" || tmp+=" $i"
        done
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$tmp' -- "$cur" ) )
    fi
} &&
_screen()
{
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

    if ((cword > 2)); then
        case ${words[cword-2]} in
            -[dD])
                _screen_sessions
                return 0
                ;;
        esac
    fi

    local i
    for (( i=1; i <= cword; i++ )); do
        case ${words[i]} in
            -r|-R|-d|-D|-x|-s|-c|-T|-e|-h|-p|-S|-t)
                (( i++ ))
                continue
                ;;
            -*)
                continue
                ;;
        esac

        _command_offset $i
        return
    done

    case $prev in
        -[rR])
            # list detached
            _screen_sessions 'Detached'
            return 0
            ;;
        -[dD])
            # list attached
            _screen_sessions 'Attached'
            return 0
            ;;
        -x)
            # list both
            _screen_sessions
            return 0
            ;;
        -s)
            _shells
            return 0
            ;;
        -c)
            _filedir
            return 0
            ;;
        -T)
            _terms
            return 0
            ;;
        -e|-h|-p|-S|-t)
            return 0
            ;;
    esac

    if [[ "$cur" == -* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '-a -A -c -d -D -e -f -fn -fa -h -i -ln -list
            -L -m -O -p -q -r -R -s -S -t -T -U -v -wipe -x -X --help
            --version' -- "$cur" ) )
    fi
} &&
complete -F _screen screen

# ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
```

source of screen bash completion file: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GArik/bash-completion/master/completions/screen

Answer (score 0):

for bash completion of screen command simply install `bash-completion-extras`, it's there.

Answer (score -1):

it's possible with complete rule added to .bashrc, refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html  and
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html
example bash complete script for screen from bash-completion:

```
# bash completion for screen                               -*- shell-script -*-

_screen_sessions()
{
    local sessions=( $( command screen -ls | sed -ne \
        's|^\t\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\.[^\t]\{1,\}\).*'"$1"'.*$|\1|p' ) )
    if [[ $cur == +([0-9])?(.*) ]]; then
        # Complete sessions including pid prefixes
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '${sessions[@]}' -- "$cur" ) )
    else
        # Create unique completions, dropping pids where possible
        local -A res
        local i tmp
        for i in ${sessions[@]}; do
            res[${i/#+([0-9])./}]+=" $i"
        done
        for i in ${!res[@]}; do
            [[ ${res[$i]} == \ *\ * ]] && tmp+=" ${res[$i]}" || tmp+=" $i"
        done
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '$tmp' -- "$cur" ) )
    fi
} &&
_screen()
{
    local cur prev words cword
    _init_completion || return

    if ((cword > 2)); then
        case ${words[cword-2]} in
            -[dD])
                _screen_sessions
                return 0
                ;;
        esac
    fi

    local i
    for (( i=1; i <= cword; i++ )); do
        case ${words[i]} in
            -r|-R|-d|-D|-x|-s|-c|-T|-e|-h|-p|-S|-t)
                (( i++ ))
                continue
                ;;
            -*)
                continue
                ;;
        esac

        _command_offset $i
        return
    done

    case $prev in
        -[rR])
            # list detached
            _screen_sessions 'Detached'
            return 0
            ;;
        -[dD])
            # list attached
            _screen_sessions 'Attached'
            return 0
            ;;
        -x)
            # list both
            _screen_sessions
            return 0
            ;;
        -s)
            _shells
            return 0
            ;;
        -c)
            _filedir
            return 0
            ;;
        -T)
            _terms
            return 0
            ;;
        -e|-h|-p|-S|-t)
            return 0
            ;;
    esac

    if [[ "$cur" == -* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W '-a -A -c -d -D -e -f -fn -fa -h -i -ln -list
            -L -m -O -p -q -r -R -s -S -t -T -U -v -wipe -x -X --help
            --version' -- "$cur" ) )
    fi
} &&
complete -F _screen screen

# ex: ts=4 sw=4 et filetype=sh
```

Comment: describe the rule you want more concrete, i can write one

Comment: Say I have a screen `12354.pts-0.slave9`, I want to type `screen -r 1` + `Tab`, and then I get `screen -r 12354.pts-0.slave9`

Comment: echo "complete -W '12354.pts-0.slave9' screen -r" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: This rule seems only auto complete the string `12354.pts-0.slave9`. I suppose it doesn't work for other screen names like `2341.pts-1.slave9`?

Comment: echo "complete -W '12354.pts-0.slave9 2341.pts-1.slave9' screen -r" >> ~/.bashrc

Comment: add any screen you like to the list.

Comment: It seems I need to change the rule whenever I create a new screen? I think there must be a smarter way since many Ubuntu machines have the built-in feature that can tab-complete all created screens.

Comment: you can list out all the screen in an string, then pass the string in the complete rule

Comment: like complete -W "$screens" screen -r

Comment: or sudo apt-get install bash-completion

Comment: I understand your point, but it is still not elegant since I need to change the list whenever I create a screen.

Comment: bash-completion package should have the function you want, since i've not used screen, i don't know to list out all the screen name automatically

Comment: I just find that the machine that does not have this tab completion feature is actually Red Hat. And `_init_completion` does not work in Red Hat (also Mac OS). Sorry for the wrong problem description.

Comment: Since my Ubuntu machines all have the built-in tab completion feature, I can't test the script myself. I think it possibly works fine. Thank you. I think I'll use the workarounds mentioned in the problem description for my Red Hat machine.